# How to delete cookies in code at application launch

Tags: jquery, cookies, model-view-controller

I'm saving some data in the cookies like

```
setCookie("ve", value , null);
```

setting to null ,so  it will expire when we click the browser.

They do get deleted when i click the browser but how to ensure the cookie gets deleted when i close my tab too? Because when I'm doing using multiple tabs and close the tab of the application my cookie is still alive.

Currently im doing this

```
deleteCookie("ve");
```

Also, I would like to delete cookie on application launch irrespective of the browser/tabs.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use it on event `onbeforeunload` or `onunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 deleteCookie("ve");
}
```

Comment: When we use window.onbeforeunload event or onunload event , the cookie will be deleted when we redirect from one url to another url within the same domain right? So how to delete cookie at the launch of the application or on closing the tab. i'm  new to Javascript/Jquery so please help me understand. Thanks